How can I globally change from light to dark theme in my app?
I'm asking for help because I have an application in which I use primevue, and I can't find my way around configuring the light and dark theme.
I've read on the PrimeVue website how to do it, but I can't get it to work.
I'm sending my Main.js file
unless I need to add a piece of code somewhere to make it work?
Main.js:
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import App from './App.vue';
import Aura from '@primevue/themes/aura';
import router from './router'; 

import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
import './style.css';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router); 
app.use(PrimeVue, {
  theme: {
    preset: Aura,
    options: {
      prefix: 'p',
      darkModeSelector: 'system',
      cssLayer: false
    }
  }
});

app.mount('#app');


To change the theme for the app, you need to add/remove the .my-app-dark class to the HTML tag of the page. To do this, we have to create a button and on click toggle the class .my-app-dark by running following code - document.documentElement.classList.toggle('my-app-dark')
Reference - https://primevue.org/theming/styled/#darkmode

But why should I add any button. I just want to permamently change my theme to dark.

set darkModeSelector: 'dark' to set the dark mode as default theme

nothing happend brother....
